# Adding Information to Maintenance mode message

Tags: maintenance-mode

I'm trying to setup my maintenance mode message so that it will display a twitter feed and a facebook like box to my sites facebook page. I want to do this so I have a place to send information to the people who need it or want to keep up to date while I do something that could have the site in maintenance for an extended period of time. I'm just wondering how I would set that up and if it's possible in the default maintenance mode settings of if I have to do something else, like a separate page or module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to add some text I'd say go into the admin settings of /admin/config/development/maintenance and update the text but if you want to add dynamic code like a facebook Iframe like button you're probably better off adding the code to a custom maintenance-page.tpl.php in your theme. Grab the code from Facebook and twitter and paste.

Just add it below the line that reads

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```

Drupal api reference - https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!maintenance-page.tpl.php/7

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my themes I use, should make things easier